# Matlab - Pass varargin to a function accepting variable number of arguments

Tags: matlab

Want to write a shorthand for `fprintf(..)`.

`varargin` is a cell array. So how can I pass it to `fprintf(..)`? The latter only accepts a variable number of arrays.

The following doesn't work:

```
function fp(str, varargin)
    fprintf(str, varargin);
end
```

Giving

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

or

```
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution is:

```
function fp(str, varargin)
    fprintf(str, varargin{:});
end
```

The cell array is expanded into a comma-separated list using the `{:}` syntax.

A shortcut using an anonymous function is

```
fp = @(str, varargin) fprintf(str, varargin{:});
```